# Are infinite icmp requests to a server a good way to monitor connectivity?

Tags: ping, vps, icmp

I have a self-hosted vps server, and I want to always see its status in the system tray of my home machine(if it is reachable or not). For that purpose I wrote a simple bash script that looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

while true
do
    if ping -c 1 -W 1 vps > /dev/null
    then
        # Draw green icon in the tray
    else
        # Draw red icon in the tray
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

That's it. Can such continuous requests have any meaningful impact on bandwidth, and can a hosting provider consider such a behavior to be suspicious? Are there better ways to monitor connectivity?

Comment: I'm sure 5 second resolution would be sufficient. or (much) longer. do you really need to know the exact second that a ping fails to get a response?

Comment: Pinging a server is a good diagnostic tool that is used very frequently. Especially if the packetsize is not altered, this is not going to give any trouble. Unless the provider thinks this is done as a keep-alive method that they want to prevent, its unlikely they're going to block ICMP responses. A ping every 1 second may be overkill though. 2,5 seconds is still very good, but 1 minute is probably still very good.

Comment: > do you really need to know the exact second that a ping fails to get a response? Actually, no. Can too frequent requests lead to problems?

Comment: The only thing too frequent pings can do, is give you unrest if the connection drops irregularly. All it tells you, is that somewhere between your internet and the VPS, the ping did not arrive. It is more likely that your own internet is less stable than the VPS, which brings me to another point, the VPS may go down but the network interface may still reply to your ping. Its not actually a good way to know if your VPS is working or not.

Comment: > Its not actually a good way to know if your VPS is working or not. I get it, thank you for your response! Can you suggest a better way to do it?

Comment: so monitoring is generally more complex than just reach-ability, but if that is all you are worried about, I'd bump up your sleep time to a minute or so. if you are more worried about the services being hosted on your VPS, you should look into options for testing the service directly, rather than just pinging the host. for instance if you are hosting a website, perhaps a service like this would fit the bill: https://www.pingdom.com/solution/website-availability-monitoring/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment exchange made me think more about the question and that eventually lead to a train of thought warranting an actual answer.

The answer is going to be no, pinging is not a good way to monitor connectivity to a VPS, if it is your goal to know if the VPS is up or down.

A ping (or ICMP request) in this question sends a small packet from your computer, to your router, to the internet, to the datacenter, to their routers and possibly to a server and finally to your virtual instance on that server.

Often, datacenters will have smart switches in their network that detect ICMP requests and those switches will respond and acknowledge your ICMP request. Pinging will not tell you if your VPS is running or not.

In addition, if you ping from your computer, and somewhere in your network, there are issues: eg. bad internet connectivity, a modem/router that has issues, will not be able to send out the ICMP request giving a bad request response which, given that you ping your VPS may give you a trigger that the VPS is down, but actually it was your own internet that was not working.

Home networks are far more often not working correctly compared to datacenter networks and VPS servers.

A VPS can of course go down, but using ICMP packages is not going to tell you if that is the case or not.

In many cases, when you rent a VPS, the provider also has a service status page that you can look up. This page is often auto-generated by monitoring tools and they are more accurate.

In addition, it is also possible to install monitoring tools on your VPS that periodically check in with a remote server, and if that check in failed, the remote server then says: "Hey, I missed a check in from server X", and sends you an email if that happens say... 5 times in a row.

This last one is the best way for you to go. If you are good in programming, you could program something simple in php, though you would need a webhosting service elsewhere. The VPS would open a url in a browser, that page refreshes itself every 10 seconds and that page also writes the last refresh in a log. A cron job on that same webserver checks for that last refresh and if it happened too long ago, emails you.

Of course, if the VPS reboots, you would have to open the browser again, but there are ways to automate that.

There are also programs out there specifically for monitoring servers, but I can't think of any off the top of my head that is cheap.

Comment: `Often, datacenters will have smart switches in their network that detect ICMP requests and those switches will respond and acknowledge your ICMP request.` That doesn't really sound plausible, but I suppose crazy things happen all the time.

Comment: @TomYan at work, we have servers where we rent serverspace from a datacenter, and they have switches that have DoS protection and they also respond to the ICMP requests rather than relaying it to the servers themelves. The reason is that they have an infrastructure where multiple servers can be behind the same public IP but using port mapping allow access to different instances, so they had to set that up and decided to just use that config everywhere. They can make exceptions and send the ICMP request to different servers, but we decided that wasn't really necessary.

Comment: I do believe the ICMP handling is part of the DoS protection if that makes sense.

Comment: That sounds more like the infrastructure is just doing basic NAT (much like a home router would), and any inbound traffic that's not explicitly DNATed to some server is handled by the gateway itself (to which the actual public IP address is assigned), which happens to include ICMP. So doing that as part of NAT makes a lot of sense, but doing it as part of a DoS protection system – not so much. (If the level of ICMP pings becomes problematic more likely they'd just get dropped entirely, instead of wasting resources answering them.)